# Margin on MediaElement cutting off parts of the video when resized

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

When I resize the window containing my MediaElement to be smaller in height, while the video scales as expected, it also seems to crop the bottom of the video slightly, which I can see through fixed elements in the video being played disappearing off-screen. Any ideas as to how I can fix this? I need the margin there to be able to have playback control buttons running along the bottom of the window, outside of the area that the video is playing in.

**XML Code**

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideoPlayer" 
              Height="370" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="650" 
              Cursor="Hand"  
              Stretch="Uniform" 
              AllowDrop="True" Drop="VideoPlayer_Drop">

<Button Content="Play" Height="21" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Margin="270,0,290,10"/>
```

**Resizing Code**

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    VideoPlayer.Height = MainContainer.Height;
    VideoPlayer.Width = MainContainer.Width;
    VideoPlayer.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 32);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `Width` and `Height`, try using `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of MainContainer like this `VideoPlayer.Height = MainContainer.ActualHeight`.

Comment: Makes no difference that I can see, the bottom still gets cut off. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Margin on MediaElement cutting off part of the video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970650/margin-on-mediaelement-cutting-off-part-of-the-video)